# Error loading model properties in JPA on play 2.0.3

Tags: hibernate, playframework, jpa-2.0

I have a very simple model called "Scholar" with corresponding getter/setter methods. I also have one method findByFullName(String name, String surname) to retrieve a List based on input name or surname.
    `@Entity`
    `@Table(name="scholar")`
    `public class Scholar extends Model {`
    `@Id`
    `@Column(name = "student_number")`
    `private long studentNumber;`
    `@Column(name = "surname")`
    `private String surname;`
    `@Column(name = "name")`
    `private String name;`

My findByFullName has method is like :
    `public static List<Scholar> findByFullName(String name, String surname) {`
    `List<Scholar> returned = JPA.em().createQuery("from Scholar s where s.surname=?")`
    `.setParameter(1, surname).getResultList();`

The resulting Scholar List has Scholar objects which ONLY have studentNumber. Name and surname return null even though the scholar table has data for both columns. i.e.

```
returned.get(0).getStudentNumber returns a value
returned.get(0).getName() returns null
returned.get(0).getSurname() returns null
```

Exception trace:
    Internal server error, for request [POST /search] ->

```
play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1$$anon$1: Execution exception [[NullPo
interException: null]]
at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:134) [
play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.3]
at play.core.ActionInvoker$$anonfun$receive$1.apply(Invoker.scala:115) [
play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.3]
at akka.actor.Actor$class.apply(Actor.scala:318) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
at play.core.ActionInvoker.apply(Invoker.scala:113) [play_2.9.1.jar:2.0.3]
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:626) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:197) [akka-actor.jar:2.0.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at models.Scholar._ebean_get_surname(Scholar.java:4) ~[classes/:na]
    at models.Scholar.getSurname(Scholar.java:89) ~[classes/:na]
    at models.Scholar.findbyIdOrNames(Scholar.java:55) ~[classes/:na]
    at controllers.Search.findScholar(Search.java:30) ~[classes/:2.0.3]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$apply$11$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(ro
     utes_routing.scala:92) ~[classes/:na]
    at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$apply$11$$anonfun$apply$12.apply(ro
    utes_routing.scala:92) ~[classes/:na]
```

My persistence.xml looks like:

```
    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence        http://java.sun.com    /xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="defaultPersistenceUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>DefaultDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

My Application.conf file looks like:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/DBName" 
db.default.user=user
db.default.password=password
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit

db.default.jndiName=DefaultD`
```

I want to retrieve all the Scholar properties; studentNumber, name and surname Please assist, literally stuck with no way forward